# Nvidia graphic driver 1650 is not recognized

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, additional-drivers

I recently bought Lenovo Legion Y540 i7 9th gen and Nvidia GTX 1650 Laptop.
I decided to dual boot it with ubuntu 18.04.

The steps I followed were:
1. Creating a bootable pen drive for ubuntu 18.04
2. I forgot the secure boot step actually.
3. in the grub I pressed e and added nouveau.modeset=0
4.then continued installation. 
5. I had created a 200 GB partition in the hard drive.
6. gave 70 GB root and 130 GB home

For additional driver I added 435 Nvidia proprietary driver Software and Updates.
However, Device info shows LLVMPIPE 9.0 256Mb
so the graphic card is not recognized, I even tried `nvidia-smi` in the terminal
which gives the result that driver should installed first though I have already installed it

```
prime-select query' only shows Nvidia and no version
```

I need help figuring this out, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows or on a Mac https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos.

Answer (score 0):

I personally solved this after 1 week by install third party software during installation.

This way my nvidia was automatically detected and installed properly. Actual Kernel isn't supporting every Nvidia model.

I have Nvidia GTX 1050 for notebooks. I am using power saving mode / INTEL /, of course can be switched in Nvidia x server settings.

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer. If you try to help people, be more elaborate. Please extend your answer by clicking the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1244662/edit) button and explain how you achieved this (e.g. by selecting a checkbox etc)